# Microsoft Breaksentence Method

Tags: c#, break

has anybody tried Microsoft BreakSentence Method in C#? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512410

I am trying to build to break the sentence input from text box using Microsoft break sentence method. However, I encountered a problem using this method.

If I type sentence ended with ".", the break sentence is correct, however, the "." is gone, attached the picture.
[image: with .]

I am fine with this situation, since only "." is missing. However, the problem came if the user types without "." at the end at the sentence.
The result will be like this attached picture.
[image: without .]

Do you know why this happened? please let me know if you have experienced this.

Here is my code.

```
 string uri5 = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/BreakSentences?text=" + English.Text + "&language=en";
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri5);
    httpWebRequest1.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
    using (WebResponse response1 = httpWebRequest1.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream1 = response1.GetResponseStream())
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer dcs = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<int>));
        List<int> result = (List<int>)dcs.ReadObject(stream1);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.WriteLine("BreakSentences broke up the above sentence into " + result.Count + " sentences.");
           int curPos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = text.Substring(curPos, result[i] - 1);
            string uri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(arr[i]) + "&from=" + "en" + "&to=" + "ja" + "&category=" + category;
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            using (WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs1 = new DataContractSerializer(Type.GetType("System.String"));
                string translation = (string)dcs1.ReadObject(stream);   
                Console.WriteLine(translation);
                output = translation;
            }            
            arr2[i] = output;
            curPos += result[i];
        }        
    }
```

Comment: For the input of `my name` what are the values in `result`? What variable contains `my nam` as output?

Comment: `arr[i] = text.Substring(curPos, result[i] - 1);` is the input.
`arr2[i] = output;` is the output.

so, if the input = my name. thank you.

the input will be break into 2 sentences. "my name" (arr[0]) and "thank you"(arr[1])

Comment: For the input of `my name` what are the values in `result`? _`result` is a list of `int` - can you tell us what those values are?_